# How to make a div under another one receive a hover event?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here is an example code that demonstrate the issue

```css
.under {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}

.under:hover {
   border: 10px solid green;

}

.over {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="under">
      Hello!
  </div>

  <div class="over" data-comment="I am invisible">
  </div>
</div>
```

When the mouse hovers over the `over` div, I want the `under` div to be aware of the hover event and, in this case, change the border accordingly.

However the `over` div is apparently intercepting the hover event. Can there be a pure css solution to pass the hover event to the `under` div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer events to the rescue!
Just set `pointer-events: none;` to the `.over`.

```css
.under {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}

.under:hover {
   border: 10px solid green;

}

.over {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid black;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="under">
      Hello!
  </div>

  <div class="over" data-comment="I am invisible">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, this will make the .over div ignore ALL pointer events, so javascript click handlers won't work

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust the HTML structure and detect the hover on `.over`

```css
.under {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.over:hover + .under {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.over {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="over" data-comment="I am invisible"></div>
  <div class="under">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the order of the divs and set on hover to the `over` with `~` that targets the next sibling

```css
.under {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.under:hover {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.over {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.over:hover~div {
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="over" data-comment="I am invisible">
  </div>
  <div class="under">
    Hello!
  </div>


</div>
```